# CSS start border from middle (horizontly)

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a layout where the border starts from middle of the image and merges with the below border

I have tried the following things:

- Used background image as border but it cannot acheive the same thing.
- I have ried to use :before & :after but unable to make it same like this.

Is there a way to make this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could playing around with the css `position` properties.

Hope it helps:

**html**

```html
<main>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x150.png" alt="test image">
    </div>
    <div class="line-1"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="about">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>About us</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, sequi aspernatur inventore, ullam sapiente assumenda dignissimos dolorum voluptatibus nam est vel maxime cum quas. Blanditiis vel obcaecati voluptatibus qui alias.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="line-2"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

and here is the **css**

```css
:root{
  --background-color: #ffffff;
  --border: 2px solid green;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --offset-left: 120px;
  --offset-bottom: 30px;
}

main{
  width: 90%;
  max-width:1200px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
.hero{
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.image-wrapper img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.line-1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:calc(50% + var(--offset-left));
  height:50%;
  bottom: calc(var(--offset-bottom) * (-1));
  left: calc(var(--offset-left) * (-1));
  border-top: var(--border);
  border-left: var(--border);
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  border-top-left-radius: var(--border-radius);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
.about{
  position: relative;
  top: calc(var(--offset-bottom) / 2);
}
.content{
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
  text-align: center;
}
.content h1{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  line-height:1;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.content p{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.line-2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:calc(50% + var(--offset-left));
  height:100%;
  top: calc(var(--offset-bottom) / 2);
  left: 50%;
  border-top: var(--border);
  border-right: var(--border);  
  border-top-right-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/Tyutyesz/pen/gOeepVb) to play around.